# ngClass not applying the class?

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I do:

```
           <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-invalid">
                <mat-label>ID</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="this.testData">
            </mat-form-field>
```

It puts a red underline on the field, but when I do:

```
           <mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'mat-form-field-invalid':true}">
                <mat-label>ID</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="this.testData">
            </mat-form-field>
```

It doesn't put the red underline. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngClass doesn't work with `<mat-form-field>`
You can use below syntax-

```
<mat-form-field [class.mat-form-field-invalid]="true">
```